# Which direction a wooden cube would float in water?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics, surface-tension, buoyancy

If you place an uniformly dense wooden cube in water, would it float:

- face up
- vertex up
- edge up

And why would that be the case?

Answer (score 1):

You should study the condition of buoyancy stability for these three cases: the center of gravity must be below the metacenter (http://www.cns.gatech.edu/~predrag/courses/PHYS-4421-13/Lautrup/buoyancy.pdf).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/277486)

Comment: @JMac : I did include the essential part: the center of gravity must be below the metacenter.

Comment: @akhmeteli: I am mildly curious about the orientation of the cube.  I still don't know even after reading your answer.  Your answer shouldn't rely on a linked document, especially a 16-page linked document where you don't give a relevant page number.  As a matter of, that document doesn't even answer the question.  It is left to the student as problem 3.13 on the last page.  The document seems like a very good reference, but you should have probably provided the link in a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Well the funniest part of this is that the person assumes that I am a student to lazy to do my homework when I have left uni for already 20 years ... just did not study physics :)

Comment: @BlueTrin : First of all, I did not want to offend anybody. Your question, however, does have the "homework-and-exercises" tag and looks very much like homework. There is nothing wrong with that, but that means that I could not give a complete solution, so I just gave a hint. Even if the hint is not enough, I cannot do anything about that.

Comment: @James : "I am mildly curious about the orientation of the cube. I still don't know even after reading your answer." And I have no idea which orientation is the most stable. I have been criticized a few times for giving a complete solution to a homework question, which is indeed in tension with the rules of the forum, now you are criticizing me for not giving a complete solution? I had not even known before I read your comment that my link contains this problem. My answer just provides the (correct) hint: calculate the position of the metacenter, and I provided the link just as a source.

Comment: @akhmeteli: Your link really is a great reference for the solution methodology.  When I commented, I hadn't noticed the "Homework" tag.  Just so you know, it wasn't the OP who added that tag.

Comment: No offense taken, I have read parts the document and I am the one who upvoted your answer :) I did not read thouroughly the PDF though but does it explain why this position is the most stable ? If not, I will just finish reading this weekend.

Comment: @BlueTrin : I don't know what you mean by "this position". The general approach is to check which of the positions (cube face/edge/vertex up) are stable. One can use the stability condition 3.28 of the link. I did not perform any calculations, so I don't know if there is always only one stable position (up to symmetry).

Comment: the most stable is face up because it will minimise the condition